# VBA Error9 exporting to pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, subscript

Using Excel VBA, I'm trying to print as PDF a single sheet of my workbook.

I am using this code:

```
    Private Sub cmd_Print_Design_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Design Summary", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

    End Sub
```

The code does not run and I get `ERROR 9 "Subscript out of Range"`. I can't understand how to solve it.

Comment: Is there a sheet called "Sheet1" in the active workbook when the procedure runs?

Comment: The only errors I could get it to produce was if Sheet1 didn't exist, the file hadn't been saved (so ThisWorkbook.Path has no value) or if the sheet contained no data - and then it was error 1004.

Could it be something else causing the problem?  e.g this code will cause an error#9 `Dim a(1 To 5) As Variant: a(6) = 1`

Look at this link for causes of error#9:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Mat'sMug I changed the name of the file and now I get error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument". The debugger underline the same code.

Comment: Try changing the `/` for a `\`. It would be a good idea to store the result of the concatenation in a variable so you could inspect it, instead of inlining it.

Comment: Woops that was meant to be a backslash.. forgot they escape in backticks. Note to self: double up backslashes in backticks/comments.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, the path separator is a backslash `\` so change this line of code:

```
Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Design Summary",
```

to

```
Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Design Summary",
```